# read port on server with socket programming

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0

i have a trouble with my socket programming code.
when i use below:

```
       var ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100");
        IPAddress add = new IPAddress(ipaddress.GetAddressBytes());

        TcpListener tcpListener = null;
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(add, 53);
        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);

            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //Read the data stream from the client. 
            byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            SocketHelper helper = new SocketHelper();
            helper.processMsg(tcpClient, stream, bytes);
        }
```

i receive this error:

Additional information: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

but i changed my cod to below :

```
 static Socket sktListener;
 var ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100");
        IPAddress add = new IPAddress(ipaddress.GetAddressBytes());
sktListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(add, 53);

        sktListener.Connect(ipLocal);

        if (sktListener.Connected)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
            int i = sktListener.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
        }
```

but it dose not any work. and stop on this line

```
int i = sktListener.Receive(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IPAddress.Parse()` returns a new `IPAddress` object, you do not need to create a second `IPAddress` object from the first object's bytes:

```
IPAddress add = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100");
```

Regarding the usage error in the first code, it means 192.168.1.100:53 is already in use by another socket.

Your second code is not creating a server, it is creating a client that connects to a server.  Assuming these codes are meant to work together, then it makes sense why `Receive()` is blocking - your client is expecting to receive data that your server is not sending.  Your server code is expecting a new client to send data, but your client is not sending anything.